# WebView --- Not able to write in the google textbox

Tags: java, android, webview, android-webview

**EDITED - Image Link:** http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=4qir6v&s=6

I have created a simple web browser in webview as shown in the pic. I am well able to navigate websites by clicking the sites or writing url in the text column (left of GO button) but am not able to write inside the webview i.e cant write in the search box as can be seen in the pic.

this is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="10" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etURL"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2" >
        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bGo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="8"
            android:text="Go" >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="8" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bBack"
            android:layout_width="115dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Back" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bForward"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Forward" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bRefresh"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="8"
            android:text="Refresh" >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/WebEngine"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="17.26" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You can upload pictures to other sites, then link to them from here.

Comment: Thnks for the suggestion... I have added the image link in the edit : http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=4qir6v&s=6

Comment: OK. Now, what do you mean by "cant write in the search box"? What specifically have you tried to do to "write in the search box"?

Comment: i clicked on the google textbox. Now on clicking the textbox cursor starts blinking there but when i type it types at the Edit box (on leftside of go button)

Comment: Any helpful comment or clarification would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the answer at the below link
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7189

```
webview.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
        webview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        if (!v.hasFocus()) {
                            v.requestFocus();
                        }
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```